# What does the following assembly instruction mean "mov rax,qword ptr gs:[20h]"

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64

Could someone please explain what the following assembly instruction means ?

```
mov rax,qword ptr gs:[20h]
```

I found the following article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400274/why-is-the-use-of-the-ds-segment-override-illegal-in-64-bit-mode) which is really helpful in explaining some things with respect to the segment override but I still do not understand what exactly is gs:[20h] is pointing at. Would the gs prefix segment override be pointing at a TEB or the PEB structure in 64 bit mode ?

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz thanks. I'm working on Windows 8.1 64 bit at the moment. But could you address this same question if I'm using Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Is that where GCC keeps the per-thread random cookie for `-fstack-protector-strong` on Windows?  If the 2 next instructions store RAX to the stack and then zero it out (to avoid leaking the cookie), that's what those instructions are doing.