# Is %gs caller- or callee-save for the System V AMD64 ABI?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, abi, memory-segmentation

Does the System V AMD64 ABI say anything about the segment register %gs?  Is it considered caller-save or callee-save? Or is it reserved? Or is nothing yet defined for %gs?

Comment: I suppose you know where to get the ABI document itself, and have already searched through it for `gs`.  But there are no relevant hits.

Comment: Note that typical use for `%gs` or `%gs.base` would be to set it up in a utility function somewhere, and then leave it set for the rest of the program until further notice, like a global variable.  Making it either caller-saved or callee-saved would make that strategy impossible.  Anyway it is certainly not reserved - I do believe it's intended to be available for the programmer's use.

Comment: Yes, I haven't found it by searching through the ABI document I have, so I have been wondering whether there is actually something stated about it anywhere. I have been thinking of using it to access thread-local data for assembler code that is generated at runtime.  The problem with "intended to be available for the programmer's use" is that it makes programs or libraries non-composable.  Callee-save would actually be best for me.

Comment: At the least, I think you could safely assume that any code which didn't follow a "callee saved" policy, at least at its external interfaces, would need to prominently document that fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, the calling convention / ABI doesn't have much to say about it at all.  The FS base is used for thread-local storage on x86-64 System V, but anything you want to do with the GS base (and/or the GS segment-selector *value*) is presumably up to you to define how your program uses it.

Either in terms of a calling convention, or more normally as set-once early in a thread's lifetime and leave untouched after that.  Like how MXCSR and the x87 rounding mode / precision control are handled by having functions leave them untouched except for maybe local changes that are restored before making any further calls.  (That is still something you can describe as a calling convention / ABI, but as Nate commented, it's neither call-preserved nor call-clobbered.)

I think the Linux kernel will save/restore user-space's selector value (and maybe also the segment base separately from whatever's in some GDT or LDT entry selected by a non-0 selector value, instead set via a system call to write the MSR, or via `wrgsbase` if the kernel enables it for user-space use on HW that supports it.)  If so then it would be viable for user-space to use GS for something, like an alternate TLS.

In practice, you can safely assume that calls to compiler-generated code (or even hand-written) in libraries won't change it.  So system calls and context switches are all you need to worry about; I'd recommend testing.

Note that `mov` to GS with a value that isn't `0` or a valid selector for an LDT or GDT entry will fault, so there's a very limited set of values you can use.

It's also quite slow to write GS ([Is a mov to a segmentation register slower than a mov to a general purpose register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163779/is-a-mov-to-a-segmentation-register-slower-than-a-mov-to-a-general-purpose-regis)), although reading it is fairly efficient (except on P4).  Perhaps even more efficient than a thread-local-storage memory location, although GS can't be a source operand for instructions other than stores.

---

Fun fact: i386 SysV uses GS for TLS; I think x86-64 changed to FS so the kernel-GS (which is special because of `swapgs`) could just be for finding the task's kernel stack after `swapgs`, not also having to be the kernel's TLS base for per-core variables.

Comment: (This is off the top of my head; will search the ABI PDF later, unless someone can confirm or correct me before then.)

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the ABI PDF, but I am far from being an expert in understanding all its details.

Comment: As for GS base vs. segment-selector value: I am interested in the former.

Comment: You say it is slow to `mov` to GS.  Do you happen to know about `wrgsbase`?

Comment: @Marc: I don't, and https://uops.info/table.html doesn't have any info on it either.  If the segment base is renamed it should be decently fast (not needing to drain the ROB); it also doesn't need to trigger a GDT or LDT load and parse the entry.  But OTOH it's a rare instruction (normally only a couple times per context switch) so it doesn't *need* to be heavily optimized.  It could well still be multi-uop, and might be worse than using TLS memory.  Or might not, if you're lucky, on Intel and/or AMD.