# Can segment registers be freely modified in x86 and x86_64 processors?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers, memory-segmentation

I want to use `rep insw` instruction. Operands for this instruction are predetermined. It looks like this:

```
rep insw (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
```

`dx` and `rdi`are general-purpose registers so I can freely modify them. What about `es`? It points to "extra data". I have never used it and I don't know what it means. It would be nice if I could set it to zero and `rdi` to linear address. Will something break if I set these (segment) registers to any value like general-purpose registers?

Comment: CS/DS/ES/SS base addresses are already fixed at 0 on x86-64.  Whether you can put a random *selector* value (index into GDT) into them is a separate question.  If you just want a flat virtual address space, you don't have to do anything at all in 64-bit code, just avoid FS and GS segment overrides (no instructions use them implicitly).  In practice, same for 32-bit code under any mainstream OS, and in your own custom kernel code where you're using `insw` if you set up the GDT that way.

Comment: [Is segmentation completely not used in x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57222727) is a possible duplicate.  Does that answer everything you were wondering?  Also related, [Why segmentation cannot be completely disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49811461) covers the vestiges of segmentation that are necessary to keep the CPU happy.